# How to initiate a call from Android Wear on notification action

Tags: wear-os

I have the following code but its not opening the dialer.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
String uri = "tel: " + requestDetail.driver.phone_number.trim();
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));



PendingIntent callPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.uber_badge)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 300, 500, 300, 500, 300, 500, 300})
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentText("Driver Accepted\nETA: " + requestDetail.eta + " mins")
        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setContentIcon(R.drawable.uber_badge))
        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setBackground(bitmap))
        .addAction(R.drawable.phone_call_image, null, callPendingIntent)
        .setLargeIcon(bitmap);
mNotificationManager.notify(notifyId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Persmissions were missing in the AndroidManifest.xml

We need to add the CALL_PHONE permission in both wearable app as well as phone app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```